# Using focus() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use JavaScript to Make Focus on Text Box.But It does't works,Please tell the way to Using focus() and set null value for that text Box.

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () 
{
   var str = ('@ViewData["ControlView"]'); //alert(str);
   if (str == "1")
       ShowProduct();
   else
       ShowGrid();
});
var message = ('@ViewData["Success"]');
if (message == "Product Code Already Exits.")
{
   document.getElementById("Item_Code").value ="";
   document.getElementById("Item_Code").focus();
}
```

View:

`@Html.TextBox("Item_Code", "", new { @Maxlength = "10", id = "Item_Code" });`

Comment: In which event you want to set focus.

Comment: Could you show the generated HTML?

Comment: are you sure that `message == "Product CodeAlready Exits."` return `true`?

Comment: Maybe it's `Product Code Already Exists.`.

Comment: try whether the condition meets or not by alerting some text in the function.

Comment: @PraveenS Remove the condition and check whether it does or not

Comment: alert func and it show Viewdata(

Comment: @PraveenS can you show us your full javascript code

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var str = ('@ViewData["ControlView"]');
        //alert(str);
        if (str == "1")
            ShowProduct();
        else
            ShowGrid();
    });
    var message = ('@ViewData["Success"]');
    if (message == "Product Code Already Exits.") {
     document.getElementById("Item_Code").value ="";
document.getElementById("Item_Code").focus(); 
    }

Comment: after this `var message = ('@ViewData["Success"]');` write `alert(message)` if you get `Product Code Already Exits.` then focus will have to work if not try chnaging `@Html.TextBox("Item_Code", "", new { @Maxlength = "10", id = "Item_Code" });` to `<input type='text' id='Item_Code' />`

Comment: i tried alert works and it shows Product Code Already Exits as a message

Comment: Try using `<input type='text' id='myItem_Code' />` instead of `@Html.TextBox("Item_Code", "", new { @Maxlength = "10", id = "Item_Code" });`And try to focus with `document.getElementById("myItem_Code").focus()` If you are really getting that alert working then I doubt that you might have more than one element with `id=Item_code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Jquery solution**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () 
{
   var str = ('@ViewData["ControlView"]'); //alert(str);
   if (str == "1")
       ShowProduct();
   else
       ShowGrid();
});
var message = ('@ViewData["Success"]');
if (message == "Product Code Already Exits.")
{
  $("#Item_Code").val("");
  $("#Item_Code").focus();
}
```

Comment: `$("#Item_Code").val();` not assign empty string to input

Comment: @Grundy added the missing "" :)

Answer (score 1):

The code for focus() in Javascript is:

```
var message="message";
if(message=="")
{
    document.getElementById("Item_Code").focus();
    document.getElementById("Item_Code").value=="";
}
```

Comment: I use this method but it don't focus on that text box

Comment: did you check whether the function works or not. There is no mistake in the syntax. Its perfect. May be there is some problem with the function. Try alerting something inside the function and check whether alert is working or not.

Comment: alert doesn't works when place after document.getElementById("Item_Code").focus();, it works before.

Comment: then there is problem with the textbox. Are you sure there is only one textbox with the name Item_Code in your form. Check whether the textbox is created or not. You can inspect element using browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery it's easier and clean

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $('#Item_Code').focus();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this script block

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () 
    {
        var str = ('@ViewData["ControlView"]'); //alert(str);
        if (str == "1")
            ShowProduct();
        else
            ShowGrid();
    });

    var message = ('@ViewData["Success"]');
    if (message == "Product Code Already Exits.")
    {
        document.getElementById("Item_Code").value ="";
        document.getElementById("Item_Code").focus();
    }
```

declaration and using message variable and `document.getElementById` function call not in `ready` function, so if declaration of yours textbox after this then in call `document.getElementById("Item_Code")` return null, because element with this id has not yet been rendered

for solve put code

```
    var message = ('@ViewData["Success"]');
    if (message == "Product Code Already Exits.")
    {
        document.getElementById("Item_Code").value ="";
        document.getElementById("Item_Code").focus();
    }
```

in `ready` function like this:

```
        $(document).ready(function () 
        {
            var str = ('@ViewData["ControlView"]'); //alert(str);
            if (str == "1")
                ShowProduct();
            else
                ShowGrid();

            var message = ('@ViewData["Success"]');
            if (message == "Product Code Already Exits.")
            {
                document.getElementById("Item_Code").value ="";
                document.getElementById("Item_Code").focus();
            }
        });
```